# Why create-react-app doesn't create new app

Tags: reactjs

I installed the latest version on Node JS with npm and cannot run create-react-app.
The following problem occurs:

```
Creating a new React app in C:\wamp64\www\bob.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....tgz"}},"2.3.4":{"nam'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Ivana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-02-26T21_21_48_727Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting bob/ from C:\wamp64\www
Done.
```

Versions:

```
Node v10.15.1
npm 6.7.0
```

Can somebody help?

After running npm cache clean --force

the another error occurs:

$ create-react-app bob

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Ivana\bob.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"@babel/plugin-synta'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ivana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-27T09_18_28_856Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting bob/ from C:\Users\Ivana
Done.
```

Comment: Did you try purging `mode_modules` and installing dependencies from clean? Also in windows `npm cache clean --force` might help.

Comment: @emix what do you mean by deleting node_modules and installing dependencies from clean, how can I do that?

Comment: This is probably linked to [this github issue](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/990), try `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I tried with  npm cache clean --force and the result is after:

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"@babel/plugin-synta'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ivana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-27T09_18_28_856Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting bob/ from C:\Users\Ivana
Done.

Comment: I mean delete the node_modules and `npm install`

Comment: @emix you mean deleting in C:\Users\Ivana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules ?

Comment: Try these [steps to create a react project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#creating-an-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app)

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

(npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher)

But you used

`create-react-app my-app`

If you use npm 5.1 or earlier, you can't use npx. Instead, install create-react-app globally:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Now you can run:

```
create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: After running npm cache clean --forcem i tried npx create-react-app my-app and it works voila :) Thanks, turchak

Answer (score 1):

> I was also not able to create a new app but when I follow these step
>   then it works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a few searches, I found this :

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g
>   create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g
>   create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

So if you installed create-react-app with

`npm -g install create-react-app`

just run :

`npm -g uninstall create-react-app`
`npx create-react-app`

It should do the job

Comment: This answer worked best for me, also I didn't clean my cache but instead, I typed: `npm cache verify`.

Answer (score 0):

I was  able to solve this problem by,

running

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then

```
npm create-react-app my-app
```